Resending a multipart request once token expires
I need to refresh my token and resend my request. I am using http_interceptor for this purpose. The issue is when I try to resend a multipart request i am getting the following error:
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Can't finalize a finalized MultipartFile.
Below is the code for client, api call(both are inside a class) and retrypolicy (ignore the http call as I had replaced it.):

Client client = InterceptedClient.build(
        retryPolicy: ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy(),
        interceptors: [LoggerInterceptor()]);
 
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
            'POST',
            Uri.parse(url),
          );
          request.headers.addAll(headers);
          request.fields.addAll(fields!);

          // Add multiple images

          for (int i = 0; i < filePaths!.length; i++) {
            request.files.add(
                await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(fileKeys![i], filePaths[i]));
          }

          var streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
          response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);


class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  //Number of retry
  @override
  int get maxRetryAttempts => 1;

  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(http.BaseResponse response) async {
    //This is where we need to update our token on 401 response
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      //Refresh your token here. Make refresh token method where you get new token from
      //API and set it to your local data
      return await refreshToken(); 
     
    }
    return false;
  }
}

Future<bool> refreshToken() async {
  log("Refresh Token Initiated");
  try {
    // final response = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    return true;
    // if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    //   return true;
    // } else {
    //   return false;
    // }
  } catch (e) {
    log('Failed at refreshToken $e');
    return false;
  }
  // log("Refresh Token Terminated");
}

class LoggerInterceptor extends InterceptorContract {
  @override
  Future<BaseRequest> interceptRequest({
    required BaseRequest request,
  }) async {
     request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${UserDetails.getToken()}';
    return request;
  }

  @override
  Future<BaseResponse> interceptResponse({
    required BaseResponse response,
  }) async {
    return response;
  }
}

